# Google Cloud Run CORS preflight error on zero instances

Tags: cors, google-cloud-run, keystonejs

I try to run a Nodejs based keystonejs backend on google cloud run. And i let the service scale down to zero instances.

If i didn't hit the frontend for a while i run into a CORS preflight error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://***/admin/api' from origin 'https:/***.de' has been blocked by CORS 
policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow- 
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But if i refresh a few seconds later the site works as expected.
Refreshings in the next minutes also work well, also on other devices.

I assume the error occurs due to the downscaling to 0 instances and the server did not come up fast enough to make the needed response.

Is there a possibility to configure cloud run to handle this without "min instances = 1"?

current cors settings

```
cors: {
    origin: "https://xyz.de",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH", "HEAD"],
    maxAge: 7200,
  },
```

**added screenshots from chrome dev tools**
network on failing load
[image]

header detail 1
[image]

header detail 2
[image]

[image]

**curl X on failed run**

```html
ml@SurfaceBook3-ML:~$ curl -X OPTIONS https://roadmaptestbackend-bchawrp2qq-ew.a.run.app/admin/api
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>KeystoneJS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html,
      body {
        height: 100vh;
      }
      body {
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #fafbfc;
        color: #172b4d;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial,
          sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol';
        font-size: 15px;
        justify-content: center;
        letter-spacing: -0.005em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration-skip: ink;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga' on;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }
      h1 {
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-bottom: 0.66em;
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      p {
        color: #6c798f;
      }
      .container {
        margin-top: -4vh;
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        text-align: center;
      }
      /* Loading spinner from loading.io/css */
      .loading-spinner {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 64px;
        position: relative;
        width: 64px;
      }
      .loading-spinner > div {
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 1, 0);
        background: #172b4d;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
        width: 11px;
      }
      .loading-spinner div:nth-child(1) {
        animation: loading-spinner1 0.6s infinite;
        left: 6px;
      }
      .loading-spinner div:nth-child(2) {
        animation: loading-spinner2 0.6s infinite;
        left: 6px;
      }
      .loading-spinner div:nth-child(3) {
        animation: loading-spinner2 0.6s infinite;
        left: 26px;
      }
      .loading-spinner div:nth-child(4) {
        animation: loading-spinner3 0.6s infinite;
        left: 45px;
      }
      @keyframes loading-spinner1 {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: scale(0);
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1);
        }
      }
      @keyframes loading-spinner3 {
        0% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1);
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: scale(0);
        }
      }
      @keyframes loading-spinner2 {
        0% {
          transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translate(19px, 0);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="loading-spinner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>

      <h1>Keystone is <span id="status">loading...</span></h1>
      <p>This page will reload when the server is ready</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      const statusEl = document.querySelector('#status');
      let ready = false;

      function onReady() {
        statusEl.innerHTML = 'ready!';
        ready = true;
        location.reload(true);
      }

      function checkAndSetStatus() {
        let cancelled = false;
        fetch('/', { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } })
          .then(result => result.json())
          .catch(error => {
            // We can get back an error "Cannot parse JSON" when a HTML
            // response is returned, so we assume the server is ready
            onReady();
          })
          .then(({ loading, status } = {}) => {
            if (!loading) {
              onReady();
              return;
            }
            if (cancelled) {
              return;
            }
            switch (status) {
              case 'init-keystone': {
                statusEl.innerHTML = 'initialising...';
                break;
              }
              case 'db-connect': {
                statusEl.innerHTML = 'connecting to the database...';
                break;
              }
              case 'start-server':
              default: {
                statusEl.innerHTML = 'loading...';
                break;
              }
            }
          });
        return () => {
          cancelled = true;
        };
      }

      let cancelLastCall = checkAndSetStatus();
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        cancelLastCall();
        if (ready) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return;
        }
        cancelLastCall = checkAndSetStatus();
      }, 500);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any info on the CORS HTTP request that is being made?  I'm trying to reproduce this but haven't been able to yet.

Comment: Hi @JamesWard happy to see you trying to help me cause i struggle since 2 weeks with this issue :-) 
I added dev tool network screenshots during a failed request to my post.
Was this meant by you talking about CORS HTTP request?  

Additional info: 
backend: nodejs based keystonejs 5 
frontend: react with apollo client

Comment: It is odd that the OPTIONS request is returning HTML content & a 200 response. What is in the response body when that happens?

Comment: sorry, but where can i find this body information?
in the network area where i copied the header, the response tab says: "Failed to load response data" on all "api" entries on failed load
If you want to check by your own, see: modernworkplacebau.de

Comment: Hmm. You might have to curl it when it is broken: `curl -X OPTIONS your-url`

Comment: @JamesWard this is the result i'm getting: localhost: 
`~# curl -X OPTIONS https://modernworkplacebau.de
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.10</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @JamesWard what i'm testing today (after the curl) is that i changed the autoscaling to minimum 1 instance. And up to now it seems to work. So i assume, that i run into this error cause the error occurs faster than the backend spinning up. Is there a possibility to configure cloud run in a way to handle the OPTIONS check while the first instance is spinning up? (cause running a non productive cloud run 24/7 is not efficient)

Comment: I think maybe you are curling the wrong service. You need to curl the blah.run.app/admin.api service when it is failing (ie returning a 200).  I'd like to see what the response is when the OPTIONS request is not working correctly.

Comment: @JamesWard by the end of last week i tested if the whole thing work when i set the backend on "minimum instances = 1" -> it worked. Then i redeployed with autoscaling to zero -> get the same behavior again. Just added the new curl -X OPTIONS result to the main topic

Comment: Thanks. It is strange that the response to an OPTIONS request is the loading web page. And I'm not sure why min instances = 1 would have any impact.  I will try to reproduce this with keystonejs but will need to know what version you are using.

Comment: @JamesWard thanks a lot for the time and effort you spend helping me out. I'm using keystonejs in version 5 (because i'm using a MongoDB database and this is not yet supported with keystone next)

Comment: we are also seeing this and it happens randomly. The problem from our side is that we also have one Cloud Run instance running.